# Copying a file using an incremented variable between sessions

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code that works perfectly when it's an Excel file.
I would like to know how to do the same thing for a docx file.

here is my EXCEL code, I would like the same but for a word document.
Since there is no CELLS in word, the code below wont work obviously for word.

```
Sub CopierFichier()

Dim counter_var As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

counter_var = Cells(1, 1).Value

' copy 
Call fso.CopyFile("C:\Users\chi\Desktop\lead\TABLE.xlsm", "C:\Users\chi\Desktop\Almod\TABLE_COPIE_" + counter_var + ".xlsm")


Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value + 1

Workbooks("TABLE.xlsm").Save

End Sub
```

Comment: If the host application is Word then Cells(1,1).Value will not work as it is a reference to the Excel Cell object.  It also teaches you that Cells without s workbook.worksheet. qualification is bad practise.  If you host application is Excel then all you need to change is . .xlsm to the appropriate .<xxx> for the type of word file you wish to copy.

Comment: I know. That's what I said. I know Cells value wont work since it is a reference to Excel. I'm asking what Can I replace to make it work for a Word Document.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306281/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents

Comment: You can store the variable value in a document variable: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/document_variables_(hidden_gems_in_word).html or custom document property: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-21d604c2-481e-4379-8e54-1dd4622c6b75

Comment: You may want to look at Graham Mayor's page on numbering word documents, as for invoice numbers. See http://www.gmayor.com/automatic_numbering_documents.htm.